# ¿Como capturar cualquier tecla pulsada en android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy usando `onKeyUp()` pero no logro capturar nada, el codigo que uso es algo asi:

```
public class MenuPrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4:
                System.out.println("--- tecla: "+ keyCode);
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6:
                System.out.println("--- tecla: "+ keyCode);
                return true;
            default:
                System.out.println("--- tecla: "+ keyCode);
                return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

Ese codigo lo busque de otras preguntas de esta misma web, pero no me esta funcionando, ni si quiera muestra nada en el log. Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal o que otro metodo puedo usar.

Es un terminal movil con teclas alfanumericas, teclas de accion, teclas de funcion, etc. Quiero poder capturar esas teclas desde una actividad, no desde un editText

Gracias

Comment: La tecla pulsada en Android, pero esta tecla es la del teclado virtual, el teclado que se activa cuando escribes en un EditText por ejemplo, es así?

Answer (score 0):

prueba este código solo reemplazas la primer palabra text por el nombre de tu input, recuerda declararlo en el OnCreate.

```
text.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0) dosomething // pick the custom key from keyEvent


        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias Arnoldo, pero no tengo ningun input en esa activity. Lo que quiero es capturar teclas y segun lo pulsado hacer cosas. Por ejemplo, imaginate un menu, y dependiendo del numero que pulses accedes a la funcionalidad de un boton u otro.

Comment: Cuáles teclas?, te referes a la tecla "back" o a los botones que agregas en el layout?

Comment: Es un terminal movil con teclas alfanumericas, teclas de accion, teclas de funcion, etc. QUiero poder capturar esas teclas desde una actividad, no desde un editText